# Show horizontal progress bar while app is replicating data with CouchDB

Tags: android, couchdb, android-progressbar

How do I show a horizontal progress bar while my android app is replicating/syncing data with the CouchDB server (both for completed and fully completed)? Any example would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link from the official Android guidelines

http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html

There you have the choice between the "percentage-style" bar or a looping progress bar.

EDIT: You will find an example here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: Thanks, but Am looking for a progressbar to be shown when data is synced between my device and remote server (CouchDB) and not the usual progressbar